# Twitter bootstrap dropdown cutoff

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a fixed navbar with a dropdown menu in it.
But the dropdown menu is cutoff and not visible when clicked.

You can see a demo at http://svn.figure8.be/bootstrap/menu.html.

I hope somebody can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the bootstrap.min.css there is a property called overflow in the `.collapse` class which is set to hidden. Remove this property and it will work.
This is the class the overflow property is located in

```
.collapse {
position: relative;
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-transition: height .35s ease;
-moz-transition: height .35s ease;
-o-transition: height .35s ease;
transition: height .35s ease;
}
```

or you can just set it to visible

```
.collapse {
position: relative;
height: 0;
overflow: visible;
-webkit-transition: height .35s ease;
-moz-transition: height .35s ease;
-o-transition: height .35s ease;
transition: height .35s ease;
}
```

Comment: It didn't work for me? I could find a class named ``collapsing`` in my css

Answer (score 1):

Removing the collapse class fixes my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The collapse class causes this, it adds overflow:hidden which hides any overflow elements.